# Adding watch-only addresses to Blockchain.info through an API?

Tags: address, api, blockchain.info, watch-only

I want to set up a service to monitor the activity of various watch-only addresses. I know Blockchain.info offers an option to do URL callback notifications when a payment is made to an address in their wallet and I know you can add a watch-only address to their wallet by hand, but I can't seem to find an API call to be able to accomplish that. Is it possible to add watch-only addresses to Blockchain.info through an API call?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info), among others, is compliant to the bitcoin [JSON RPC API](https://blockchain.info/api/json_rpc_api). That given, you can use the most common programming languages to access your wallet, last but not least the simple `bitcoin-cli` command, from the original bitcoin distribution:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -rpcconnect=rpc.blockchain.info -rpcport=443 -rpcssl -rpcuser=YourWalletIdentifier -rpcpassword=YourPassword getinfo
```

`-rpcconnect=rpc.blockchain.info` will instruct `bitcoin-cli` to connect to blockchain.info's RPC interface; `-rpcport=443` specifies the remote port; `-rpcssl` needs to require a SSL connection; `-rpcuser` and `-rpcpassword` speak for themselves.

The last word, `getinfo`, is the command itself.

In your case, it should be something like:

```
importaddress <bitcoinaddress> "" false
```

where `importaddress` is the command (or method) which instructs the wallet to include the `<bitcoinaddress>` in the wallet itself. Since you don't specify the private key of the address, but just the address itself, it will become a "watch address" inside your wallet: you will be able to track its status but not to broadcast transactions which involves it. The couple of double quotes `""` can be replaced with the wallet's name, if you set one. `false` is a boolean value which instructs the bitcoin engine not to rescan the whole blockchain looking for transactions which involves the address you are adding. I am not a blockchain.info customer, so I don't know the effects of this particular flag. I believe that it is ok to set it true, since blockchain.info scans the blockchain in real time.